# Como criar uma matriz tridiagonal em Python?

Tags: python, fortran

Eu gostaria de saber como escrever uma matriz tridiagonal NxN. Eu tenho três vetores que serão atualizados em um loop.

Eu estou trabalhando com algo semelhante a isso:
[image: Example]

Nota: Eu apenas gostaria de saber sobre zeros e que parâmetros do Python eu poderia usar para ajustar isso. Bem, eu tenho dois códigos aqui, o primeiro eu escrevi em Fortran e está funcionando bem. O segundo é o que eu tentei escrever em Python.

Fortran:

```
do i=2,n-1
  do j=2,n-1
    if (i.eq.j) then

      D(i,j+1)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))

      t1 =u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))

      t2 = u_med(i)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))

      D(i,j)= t1 + t2 + V(i)

      D(i+1,j)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))

    end if

  end do
end do
```

Python:

```
for i in range(2,n):
  for j in range(2,n):
    if i == j:
      D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
      t1 = u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      t2 = u_med[i]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      D[i][j]= t1 + t2 + V[i]
      D[i+1][j]= - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])

t1 = u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[1])
t2 = 0
D[1][1]= t1 + t2 + V[1]
D[1][2]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[2])
D[2,1]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[2]*delta_r[1])
t1 = 0
t2 = u_med[n]/(delta_r[n]*delta_r[n])

D[n][n]= t1 + t2 + V[n]
```

Que dá o erro:

> D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1]) ValueError: setting
> an array element with a sequence.

Definições de `u_med`, `delta_r`, `r`, `n` e `D` em Python:

```
u_med = np.zeros((n,2))
for i in range(2,n):
  tta1 = r[i]*u[i]
  tta2 = r[i-1]*u[i-1]
  u_med[i] = 0.5*(tta1 + tta2)/(r[i] - r[i-1])

u_med[1] = u_med[2]

delta_r = np.zeros((n-1,2))
for i in range(2,n-1):
  ft1 = r[i+1]*r[i+1]
  ft2 = r[i-1]*r[i-1]
  ft3 = 2*r[i]*(r[i+1] - r[i-1])
  delta_r[i] = math.sqrt(0.125*abs(ft1 - ft2 + ft3))

ri=0
n1 = 51

r1 = ri
r2 = 250
hr1 = (r2-r1)/(n1-1)

r = np.zeros((n1,1))
for i in range(n1):
  r[i] = r1 + i*hr1

u = np.zeros((n+1,1))
for i in range(1,n+1):
  i = 1

D = npm.zeros((n,n))
```

Eu suspeito que o erro esteja em:

```
D = npm.zeros((n,n))
```

Mas como eu poderia reescrever isso?

Comment: Provavelmente, o problema está acontecendo devido a `u_med` e `delta_r` serem bi-dimensionais e você tentar atribuir um *sub-array* (vetor) dessas variáveis à uma posição na variável `D` com um *shape* incompatível. Isso funciona no Fortran, mas deve ser feito de forma diferente no Python. Veja: [Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays)

Comment: Na verdade `u_med` e `delta_r` são unidimensionais... `D` é que é bidimensional. De alguma forma estes estão definidos como bidimensionais?

Comment: Você definiu `u_med` como `np.zeros((n,2))` (*n* linhas e 2 colunas) e `delta_r` como `np.zeros((n-1,2))` (*n-1* linhas e 2 colunas), portanto, eles são bidimensionais

Answer (score 0):

```
# elementos da diagonal da matriz
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i == j):
        A[i][j] = 2

# elementos fora da diagonal da matriz
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if(i == j and i>=1):
             A[i][j-1] = 1
             A[i-1][j] = 1
```